# Sync iPhone Calendar events deletion with events stored in app

Tags: ios, ekeventkit

I have one issue, if i adding event in calender through the app and if delete that added event from simuloter calendar delete button. Then it will also delete from app, is this possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting rough algorithm here to sync iCal events with the events stored in you app:

```
//model class for DB Events
@interface EventEntity 

@property(strong) NSString *eventID;
@property(strong) NSString *eventText;

@end

NSMutableArray *dbEvents; //array of EventEntity objects
NSArray *iCalEvents; //array of events fetched from iCal

NSMutableArray *eventsToDelete = [NSMutableArray array]; //We will add events in this array, needed to be deleted from db.

for(EventEntity *entity in dbEvents) {
  bool found = NO; //to keep track if this event has been found in iCal or not

 for(EkEvent *event in iCalEvents) {
    if([event.eventidentifier isEqualToString:entity.eventID]) {
    found = YES; //event is present in Cal. Ignore and break
        break;
    }
 }

   if(!found) { //If not found, it means event has been deleted from iCal. Remove it from DB.
    [eventsToDelete addObject:entity];
  }
}

//Now delete items one by one from db
for(EventEntity *entity in eventsToDelete) {

//make query something like this: Delete event where EventID = entity.eventID

//after successful deletion, remove from dbEvents
[dbEvents removeObject:entity];
}

//refresh your UI for calendar/events if needed.
```

Hope it helps!